# how to identify font family from image?

Tags: font-face, webfonts, truetype

How to identify font in pictures/logo?

I am trying to find font used in logo below. As I don't have psd or ai files to find it, I tried some of the websites helpful for finding the font family but could not find the exact match.

Answer (score 3):

There are several websites that offer this service for free.

[WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) is a good service.

Step 1: upload the image, one line of the font that you want to identify is enough
[image]

Step 2: Enter the letters in the boxes as shown below
[image]

Step 3: From the given set of results, identify your font
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice [reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/identifythisfont/comments/8bshy9/you_can_find_fonts_on_your_own/) which has a lot of helpful links. And all those fail, you can always post on the sub-reddit [r/identifythisfont](https://www.reddit.com/r/identifythisfont) to see if anyone else knows.

What the reddit answer says in case the link ever breaks:

> **If you're looking for a font on a website...**
>   Use [WhatFont](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm?hl=en). It works every time. You get the name of the font, as well as colours, sizes and more.
>
> **If you have a relatively clear picture of something that contains the font...**
>   Use [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) or [Font Macherator](https://www.fontspring.com/matcherator) or [Font Squirrel Macherator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator). All these apps identify free and premium fonts. They also do a really good job at finding similar fonts and alternatives.